# How to create factor "diamond" AND factor "box" for step-by-step Algebra solutions

Tags: formatting

Please help me with the formatting code to:

1. place number values in each of the 4 quadrants of the factor diamond
2. center numbers **within** the factor box table and place numbers centered **above the 2 cells in the top row**
3. place numbers to the **left of each cell in first column**

[image: this shows where I need to place the "diamond" and the box within the solution]

Note: Numbers shown are not correct for factors. I just pasted in the images for illustration.

The numbers and variables, of course, will vary from problem to problem. As you can see from my MWE, the solution set is in a 2 column format.

Thanks very much! I'm lost without your generous assistance.

MWE.....

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers % un-comment to print solutions.
\printanswers
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{array}
% p centers horizontally in table cell
% m centers vertically in table cell
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II Review Ch 3.2: Operations Rational Expressions and Equations: K E Y}
       {}
       {01/13-14/21} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Obj. 3.2.a: I can simplify factored rational expressions and find their restrictions.
    \bigskip
    \bigskipSimplify expression and state the excluded values (+1 pt numerator, +1 pt denominator, +1 pt restrictions.) each equation. Show all work/steps on this page.}
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }
 
% ------------ DOCUMENT STARTS HERE---------------- 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

%macro \diamondscheme. The lines are drawn too, you need not tikz. The size is controlled by the \diaw parameter. It is set to 1.5cm in this example.

% definition
\newdimen\diaw \diaw=1.5cm
\def\diamondscheme#1#2#3#4{%
    \vbox to\diaw{
       \kern-1ex
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#1$\hss}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hbox to0pt{\hss$#2$\hss}\hss
                     \raise.7ex\hbox{\diacross}\hss
                     \hbox to0pt{\hss$#3$\hss}}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#4$\hss}
       \kern-1ex
    }
}
\newcount\tmpnum 
\tmpnum=\diaw 
\divide\tmpnum by65781  % tmpnum is now equal to \diaw in bp units
\divide\tmpnum by2
\def\tmp{\the\tmpnum\space}
\edef\diacross{\pdfliteral
   {q 0.4 w -\tmp \tmp m \tmp -\tmp l S -\tmp -\tmp m \tmp \tmp l S Q}}

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{10k^2+32k+24}{1k5+18}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor 2 out of the numerator.\bigskip

$\dfrac{2(5k^2+16k+12)} {15k+18}$\bigskip

Now factor the numerator using diamond method. 
\bigskip
%call diamondscheme macro
\hspace{2cm}
\diamondscheme{60}{10}{6}{16}
\bigskip
The 5 in front of $5k^2$ means this is a non-monic quadratic trinomial. So you must proceed to the box method to complete the factorization.

\vspace{0.75cm}
%Example of fixed column width and text long (array package required)
% for the vertical padding / row height
\hspace{1cm}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{2cm}| m{2cm} | } 

  \hline
  $x^2$ & $6x$  \\ 
  \hline
  $2x$ & $12$  \\ 
  \hline
 
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\bigskip
simplified form: $7x$

Zeros: $x=0$

Holes: $none$

VA: $none$
\end{solutionorbox}
% Prob #2
\task $\dfrac{3x^2-13x-10}{x-5}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{3x^2-13x-10}{x-5}$\bigskip

Nothing can be factored out of the numerator and denominator.

Now factor the numerator using diamond method. 
\bigskip
%call diamondscheme macro
\hspace{2cm}
\diamondscheme{-30}{-15}{2}{-13}
\bigskip

The 3 in front of $3k^2$ means this is a non-monic quadratic trinomial. So you must proceed to the box method to complete the factorization.

\vspace{0.75cm}
%Example of fixed column width and text long (array package required)
% for the vertical padding / row height
\hspace{1cm}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{2cm}| m{2cm} | } 

  \hline
  $x^2$ & $6x$  \\ 
  \hline
  $2x$ & $12$  \\ 
  \hline
 
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace{0.5cm}

simplified form: $?$

Zeros: $x=0$

Holes: $none$

VA: $none$
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why there are so many `\\\\ `? We are not using an old typewriter, but the typesetting system TeX.

Comment: @Wipet, I agree and edited code to remove \\\\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question 1 should be solved by the following macro `\diamondscheme`. The lines are drawn too, you need not tikz. The size is controlled by the `\diaw` parameter. It is set to 1.5cm in this example.

```
% definition
\newdimen\diaw \diaw=1.5cm
\def\diamondscheme#1#2#3#4{%
    \vbox to\diaw{
       \kern-1ex
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#1$\hss}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hbox to0pt{\hss$#2$\hss}\hss
                     \raise.7ex\hbox{\diacross}\hss
                     \hbox to0pt{\hss$#3$\hss}}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#4$\hss}
       \kern-1ex
    }
}
\newcount\tmpnum 
\tmpnum=\diaw 
\divide\tmpnum by65781  % tmpnum is now equal to \diaw in bp units
\divide\tmpnum by2
\def\tmp{\the\tmpnum\space}
\edef\diacross{\pdfliteral
   {q 0.4 w -\tmp \tmp m \tmp -\tmp l S -\tmp -\tmp m \tmp \tmp l S Q}}

%test:
\diamondscheme{20}{-4}{-5}{-9}
```

According to your `\\` in your document. Read the log file carefully. Each `Underfull \hbox` warning here is one `\\` which is badly used. If you want to add one-line space after the paragraph, then redefine LaTeX `\bigskip` by:

```
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
```

and replace all `\\` by `\bigskip`. Of course, do not do this replacing inside `tabular` environment, where `\\` are used correctly. Notice: The original LaTeX `\bigskip` is `\vadjust{\vskip\bigskipamount}` which does not finalize the current paragraph and brings only problems.

Note that you have one `Overfull \hbox` in your log too. This is due to second bad LaTeX concept: it inserts `\leavemode` before each box created by LaTeX. So, your `\fbox` in your `\pagetop` definition is shifted by `\indent` to right. Insert `\noindent` before this `\fbox`

Comment: ...your suggestions and diamondtheme macro are truly magnificent. Following your guidance re: define \bigskip eliminated the "overfull box" and "underfull" box errors. Although I've worked on this for most of the day, I can't figure out how to place 2 numbers horizontally above the top table row (one above ea. cell) and 2 numbers vertically to the left of the 1st col. (please see original screen shot above). Also, would like to vertically & horizontally center values in the cells.

Comment: @WyoWindStorm I see, there are no more responses. This is (IMHO) due to the fact, that your questions are somewhat isolated. It is not typical on this site to answer more than one question in one thread. If you put your question about 2x2 table to another thread you will get a LaTeX answer. I am able to give only TeX answer here.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice. Will follow that guidance, mark this question as answered and post separately for an assistance on the factor box.