# How can I draw a "table" with 4 numbers around a cross/X-shape for the diamond method?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to write up a precalculus explanation with LaTeX and I wanted to make this fancier "diamond table", is there any way to do it? Couldn't find it through searching

[image: (if anyone's interested, it's from Professor Leonard's lecture about completing the squares]

Comment: There's [formatting - How to create factor "diamond" AND factor "box" for step-by-step Algebra solutions - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578897/how-to-create-factor-diamond-and-factor-box-for-step-by-step-algebra-solutio) (image-searching for "diamond table" apparently.) but the answer *here* looks better (and that one is multiple-questions-in-one)

Comment: factoring trinomials?

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a `tikz` solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(1,1) (1,0)--(0,1);
\path(.5,1)node{$-6$}--(0,.5)node{$-3$}--(.5,0)node{9}--(1,.5)node{$-3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For more flexible solution, a `tikzpicture` can be encoded into a macro that contains a matrix, so the shape of the cross will adapt in case any of the entries are very long. The call is

`\diamondtable{-6}{-3}{-3}{9}` or `\diamondtable{111111}{2}{3}{4}`

[image]

An optional argument allows you to change the column sep:

`\diamondtable[-2mm]{-6}{-3}{-3}{9}\qquad\diamondtable[4mm]{111111}{2}{3}{4}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\diamondtable}[5][0mm]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix(M)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={anchor=center}, ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=#1]
    {\& #2 \& \\ #3 \& \& #4 \\ \& #5 \& \\ };
    \draw[thick](M-1-1.north west)--(M-3-3.south east) (M-3-1.south west)--(M-1-3.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\diamondtable{-6}{-3}{-3}{9}\qquad\diamondtable{111111}{2}{3}{4}

\diamondtable[-2mm]{-6}{-3}{-3}{9}\qquad\diamondtable[4mm]{111111}{2}{3}{4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aah thank you!!

Comment: To me the minus signs don’t work here. They are too big and also skew the diagram.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `\diam` macro that stacks the digits over a scaled `\times`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\diam[4]{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\scaleobj{7}{\times}}
  {\Centerstack{#1  \\
                \makebox[0pt][r]{$#2$}\kern18pt\makebox[0pt][l]{$#3$}\\
               #4}}%
}
\begin{document}
\diam{-6}{-3}{-3}{9}

\diam{6}{3}{3}{9}
\end{document}
```

[image]